# How to show picture instead of link on Twitter from Facebook posts

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have connected my Twitter account with my Facebook account. And when I post something on Facebook it also get posted on Twitter. Status get posted on Twitter same as I post on Facebook but when I post a picture on Facebook, it shows a link on Twitter instead of that picture.

Is there any way to get picture visible on Twitter instead of the link (or with the link) from posting Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the application you are using. The application will need to leverage the use of Facebook API to call the photo ID src (instead of just the Photo ID link) then post that via Twitter API.

Assuming you are using this, https://www.facebook.com/twitter/, then you will not be able to get the option to have the photo posted to Twitter as this app has not been changed in a very long while.

The closest option will be to use an IFTT recipe

[image: IFFT recipe If Facebook then Twitter]

[image: IFFT Twitter Post]

Comment: So which application I can use to show the image, can you suggest something?

Comment: It is actually not that what I am looking. With this tool if I change profile pic of FB, it changes the twitter profile pic also.

Comment: @serenesat that's not what your question asked. "when I post a picture on Facebook, it shows a link on twitter instead of that picture." Which is what the screenshots above show. I posted a photo to Facebook (you did not specify that the photo was the profile picture) a photo is posted to Twitter as well. You're going to have to check the list of recipes to come to your own solution, I feel as though I answered the question less the part not given (changing a profile picture)

Comment: In normal case (as this time) if I post any image on FB, it shows on twitter with a link, not image (I want it should show image). This tool works for it but the problem is if I change profile pic on FB it is changing twitter profile pic with same image (that should not be happen and that i don't want also). I am looking for a tool which work for showing image instead of link but do not change anything else.

Comment: [buffer](https://buffer.com/) is what I was looking for. :)