# Tweet with image: how to make it show up on Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, images

When I post a tweet with an image and I share it on Facebook, the image does not get shared, only the text. To see the image you have to click on the link and see it on Twitter. Is there a way to show the image on Facebook?

[How to show picture instead of link on Twitter from Facebook posts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/how-to-show-picture-instead-of-link-on-twitter-from-facebook-posts) is the other way around. What I want:

1. I post a tweet with an image attached
2. That goes fine on Twitter
3. My tweets are automatically shared on Facebook (via the permitted apps on Twitter) but the image is not shown on Facebook. You have to click on the tweet, thus opening another window before you get to see the picture.

*How do I make the image show up on Facebook as well?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show picture instead of link on Twitter from Facebook posts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/how-to-show-picture-instead-of-link-on-twitter-from-facebook-posts)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate to me. The other question is the opposite problem.

Comment: Check IFTTT, that have this option.